# How to designing a KeyPair interface which can handle any KeyPair implementation

Tags: java, spring-boot, design-patterns

I am designing a KeyPair interface which looks something like this,

```
public interface KeyPair {

    @Deprecated
    public Key firstKey();

    @Deprecated
    public Key secondKey();
}
```

I want to use this interface to implement two classes, `PasswordEncryptionKeyPair`, `PrivatePublicKeyPair`. But the problem is that I don't want to use the methods `firstKey()` and `secondKey()` as they are very generic. I rather want to use some other method and make these two method private. My current implementation is like this,

```
class PrivatePublicKeyPair implements KeyPair{

    public Key getPrivateKey() {
        return firstKey();
    }

    public Key getPublicKey() {
        return secondKey();
    }

    @Override
    public Key firstKey() {
        return privateKey;
    }

    @Override
    public Key secondKey() {
        return publicKey;
    }
}
```

```
class PasswordEncryptionKeyPair implements KeyPair{

   public Key getPassword() {
        return firstKey();
    }

    public Key getEncryptionKey() {
        return secondKey();
    }

    @Override
    public Key firstKey() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public Key secondKey() {
        return encryptionKey;
    }
}
```

In the first class I want to use `getPublicKey()` and `getPrivateKey()` methods to return first and second key. And in next class I want to use `getPassword()` and `getEncryptionKey()` to return first and second key.

As an interface cannot have private method I can't make the methods private. One way this is possible is by adding body in the interface itself or create an `AbstarctKeyPair` class, and make methods private there. Is there any other solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Since Java 9 interfaces **can** have `private` methods (as well as `default` and `static`).

But you **can't** override a `public` method (*all* `abstract` *methods in interfaces are implicitly* `public`) by narrowing its visibility to `private`.

I'm not sure where the interface `KeyPair` you've listed is coming from, but `@Deprecated` annotations are a huge red flag which tells *"don't use it"*.

You might consider declaring your own interface.

```
public interface KeyPair {
    
    Key getPrivateKey();

    Key getPublicKey();
}
```

Comment: The @Deprecated annotations are added because I don't want anyone to use `getFirstKey()` and `getSecondKey()` method. I want then to use method which in turn call these method(implemented in the both the child classes).

Comment: @SeemaSharma So it's your custom interface. Then speaking class design basics are you familiar with the [Open–closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle). **Contracts should not change**. If you think that is totally fine to throw away a couple of methods from an interface, then you should be aware that it's actually not. Have a look at very old badly designed interfaces (in Java, in Frameworks like Spring). No one changes interfaces, sometimes a new interfaces get introduced as a replacement, but the old ones **continue to exist as is**.

Comment: @SeemaSharma because no one wants to destroy the contract and break things. You can't simply throw away a part of the interface, unless your code is written exclusively for compiler and JVM.

Comment: Ok, I got your point. Just one thing, its not that I am not using the methods present in the interface. I am using them in both my child classes. I just want to call those function by different names in different implementations. Is this wrong or it can be done? And is this a bad design practice? If yes, what is the solution.

Comment: @SeemaSharma Let me rephrase the question you've asked in the comment. *I have an abstract type, which I **can't** benefit from. It only brings a burden of implementing it's contract, which I'm not using. And I'm writing my code against concrete classes. Is it a sign of poor design?* I guess you might be capable of answering this question yourself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248646/discussion-between-alexander-ivanchenko-and-seema-sharma).

Answer (score 1):

You can replace inheritance with aggregation.

Add `getKeyPair` method to `PrivatePublicKeyPair`.

```
public KeyPair getKeyPair() {
    return new KeyPair() {
        public Key firstKey() { return getPassword(); }

        public Key secondKey() { return getEncryptionKey(); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but don't you think implementing a KeyPair interface is a better design than adding a KeyPair variable inside the class. Because these classes are a type of KeyPair itself.

Comment: You don't need variable inside. You can create new instance each time you need it. I'll add example.

Comment: Sure, that will help a lot.